# How to get echo work from a "client" PowerShell script?

Tags: .net, scripting, powershell

I'm running a PowerShell script, which, call another script by itself. In the first script, when I put echo, everything is OK, but I can't get any echo in the second ("client") script to show anything.

How can I get echo work?

I'm using PowerShell 2.0 on Windows 7 Pro, with PowerGUI. (I also tried with ISE, but it does not help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Write-Host directly insted of echo (witch is alias for Write-Output).

Comment: It seems to be working now, but another problem: I want to print full properties of the object, but Write-Host only print their type. How can I fix that?

Comment: you should never use Write-Host to return or output something in a script. It is a best practice to always use Write-Output

Comment: ravikanth If the SO wants to write to the console, but *not* the pipeline then using write-host is the correct thing to do. The question doesn't make this distinction clear.

Comment: artem Write-Host is not an alias for Write-Output AFAIK it works differently in that it outputs to the console only, rather than to the script "output" pipeline.

Comment: @chibacity, see the first comment. He wants to print all properties. That can be done either using Format-List * or using Write-Output. I agree on the pipeline part of your response.

Answer (score 1):

A sample of your script would help in giving an accurate answer. That said, I tried Write-Output from nested scripts and everything seems to working for me.

```
#Script1.ps1
Write-Output "Script 1"
Write-Output "Calling Script 2"
./Script2.ps1

#Script2.ps1
Write-Output "Script 2"
Write-Output "Script 2 End"
```

And, the output:

```
PS> .\Script-one.ps1
Script 1
Calling Script 2
Script 2
Script 2 End
```

Comment: Seems like @Vimvq1987 calls that script indirectly. i.e. using powershell.exe

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Write-Host` to write to the console ( host)

There seems to be some confusion on using `Write-Output` vs `Write-Host` (`echo` is alias for Write-Output - you can see it from Get-Alias ). `Write-Output` is not just writing to console. From the docs:

> Sends the specified objects to the
>   next command in the pipeline. If the
>   command is the last command in the
>   pipeline, the objects are displayed in
>   the console.

Comment: That's not what Artem was saying. He was saying that `echo` is an alias of `write-output`.